# Rails: Using to_param for SEO-friendly slugs screwing up database calls?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

So in my Rails models I'm doing the following to generate an "SEO friendly" slug:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

So that generates something like: `example.com/items/1-example-title`

But when I check my logs, the SQL calls are then:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE (`items`.`id` = '1-example-title') LIMIT 1
```

That seems to work fine for MySQL, but PostgreSQL flips out on it.

So, how can I get my SQL query to just use `1` for the `id` instead of the full slug?

Comment: can you please post the code when you're calling this url?

Comment: I assume the issue is with the Postgres adapter?  I don't think that syntax would fly as raw sql for Mysql either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are using the standard find call.

```
Model.find(params[:id])
```

If you use alternative syntaxes, such as

```
Model.find_by_id(params[:id])
Model.first(:conditions => { :id => params[:id] })
```

then you need to cast the parameter to integer.

```
params[:id].to_i
```